# When proving that $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space by showing that it satisfies axiom 2, why go through all the steps?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the set of complex numbers ($\mathbb{C}$) is a vector space because it has been proven, but I want to know why we must go through all the steps (i.e. Adding the real parts AND adding the imaginary parts AND commuting the 2 elements) to finally get our $y + x$. Can't we just commute them from the start? For example:

Let $x$ and $y$ be elements in the set of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose $x = a + bi$ and $y = c + di$.

Prove that the set $\mathbb{C}$ satisfies axiom 2, $$x + y = y + x.$$
This can be shown as:
$$(a + bi) + (c + di) =
(a + c) + (b + d)i \,\,\, \text{//Complex Addition} \\
(a + c) + (b + d)i =
(c + a) + (d + b)i \,\,\, \text{//Commutative Property} \\
= (c + di) + (a + bi) \,\,\, \text{//Why must we go through all these steps?} \\$$

So basically my question boils down to this: why must we go through all these steps? Can't we just commute $x + y$ from the beginning?

For example:

$$(a + bi) + (c + di) = (c + di) + (a + bi)$$

Comment: you are basically asking: can't we just assume what is to be proven? Well of course not, unless you do not want to verify it and just assume it

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you cannot justify assuming what it is you are trying to prove: That is, that addition in $\mathbb{C}$ is commutative. Instead what you do to prove it is that you *inherit* it from another domain (namely addition on $\mathbb{R}$). You first invoke the definition of addition of complex numbers to rewrite that addition in terms of additions of real numbers. You apply commutativity of addition of real numbers in both places, and then observe that the result satisfies the definition of commutativity of addition of complex numbers.

In detail, then, using $+_{\mathbb{R}}$ for addition of reals, and $+_{\mathbb{C}}$ for addition of complex numbers:

$X+Y=(a+_{\mathbb{C}}bi)+_{\mathbb{C}}(c+_{\mathbb{C}}di)$ |By definition of complex numbers

$=(a+_{\mathbb{R}}c)+_{\mathbb{C}}(b+_{\mathbb{R}}d)i$ |By definition of complex addition

$=(c+_{\mathbb{R}}a)+_{\mathbb{C}}(d+_{\mathbb{R}}b)i$ |By commutativity of real number addition (used in two places)

$=(c+_{\mathbb{C}}di)+_{\mathbb{C}}(a+_{\mathbb{C}}bi)$ |By definition of complex number addition (opposite direction)

$=Y+X$ |By definition of complex numbers (also opposite direction)

Therefore by definition of commutativity, addition of complex numbers, $+_{\mathbb{C}}$, is commutative.

(That last line, though often omitted, is technically important to a proper formal proof, because that is what you are actually trying to prove)